How to convert the contour of a road marking line into a curve that follows the marking?
I'm using segmentation to detect road marking lines using the YOLOv8n-seg model. The segmentation mask represents the coordinates of the mask contour points in the image.
segmentation of road marking lines
I need to convert the coordinates of the mask contour points into the coordinates of the curve points that will run along the road marking line. Here's an image of what it should look like:
curve following road markings
I use KD-tree to quickly find the nearest points to find the centers of small clusters, thus drawing the points along lines. Then I needed to connect these points into a graph, but I couldn’t do it correctly - the points were constantly connected incorrectly. Here's a picture of what it looked like.
my results

This video is not at all relevant to my question. I already did the segmentation, I need to draw a curve using the segmentation mask

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
